# Angular update content on click browser back/forward

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular5, observable

Further to the question title, I have written an implementation in Angular 5 to achieve this however I failed to make it work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhtgbr

The idea is whenever a user click back or forward in their browser, application able to detect the url changes and update content if it is still in same component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Location, PopStateEvent } from '@angular/common';
import { ActivatedRoute, Event, NavigationEnd, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  template: 'Read in console'
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {

  page: number = 1;

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.detectPopState();

    setTimeout(() => this.goToPage(1), 1000);
    setTimeout(() => this.goToPage(2), 2000);
    setTimeout(() => this.goToPage(3), 3000);
    setTimeout(() => this.goToPage(4), 4000);
    setTimeout(() => window.history.back(), 5000);  // will trigger location PopStateEvent
    setTimeout(() => window.history.back(), 6000);  // Trigger twice! Expected to trigger only once
    setTimeout(() => window.history.back(), 7000); // Trigger 3 times!
  }

  detectPopState() {
    this.location.subscribe((popStateEvent: PopStateEvent) => {
      // Detect popstate
      if (popStateEvent.type === 'popstate') {
        const eventSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.page = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.page;
            this.updateContent();
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }

  updateContent() {
    console.log('Update content ' + this.page);
  }

  goToPage(page: number) {
    this.page = page;
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'], {
      queryParams: {
        page: this.page
      }
    });
    this.updateContent();
  }
}
```

The problem is here:

```
setTimeout(() => window.history.back(), 6000);  // Trigger twice! Expected to trigger only once
setTimeout(() => window.history.back(), 7000); // Trigger 3 times!
```

I understand `updateContent()` get fired cumulatively due to multiple subscribe inside PopStateEvent change detect but I am struggling to find a workaround to achieve the behaviour I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not unsubscribing the subscription of `router.events` (observable). So, you ended up with memory leaking.

Solution:

Unsubscribe the subscription of `router.events`

```
this.location.subscribe((popStateEvent: PopStateEvent) => {
      if (popStateEvent.type === 'popstate') {
        const eventSubscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
          if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
            this.page = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.queryParams.page;
            this.updateContent();

            // Here it is
            eventSubscription.unsubscribe();

          }
        });
      }
    });
```

It is now working perfectly. [You can test from Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhtgbr-wtbhpk?file=src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts). (Make sure open the output in new window)

Comment: I swear I have tried your attempt before posting but it is now works for me!